# Clojure: chop of the first space separated characters

Tags: string, parsing, filter, clojure

I want to parse and filter a file that looks like this:

```
@@1 Row one. 
@@2 Row two.
```

I have been able to do the filtering of the rows with the following code:

```
(defn parse-text-cms [sel-row]
  (let [f_data  (st/split  #"@@" (slurp "cms/tb_cms.txt"))] 
  ;(prn (map #(take 1 %) f_data))))
  (filter  #(= (first (take 1 %)) sel-row) f_data)))
```

However, this codes gives me (if sel-row=1):

```
1 Row one.
```

I would like to chop off that 1 and the space after, so to have:

```
Row one.
```

I think there is some sequence magic to do this. I just can't come up with an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define the function the following way:

```
(defn parse-text-cms [sel-row]
  (with-open [input (clojure.java.io/reader "cms/tb_cms.txt")]
    (first
     (for [[_ number line] (map (partial re-find #"@@(\d)+\s+(.*)")
                                (line-seq input))
           :when (= number (str sel-row))]
       line))))
```

The combination of `line-seq` and `reader` gives me a sequence of lines from the input file. `with-open` ensures that the file is properly closed when I'm done. I apply a regex to each line that looks for `@@` followed by a number and some spaces.

`re-find` returns a vector with three items:

- the whole matched line
- the number (the first group in the regex)
- the rest of the line (the second group in the regex)

I bind these to `number` and `line` using destructuring in a `for` statement (I'm not interested in the whole matched line, so I ignore that). I filter for the selected `sel-row` using `:when` and yield only the (rest of the) `line`.

Since I only expect one match in the file, I return just the first item from the sequence built by `for`. Because of the laziness of `for`, `map` and `line-seq`, this also stops reading of the file after the item is found.

If you do a lot of lookups for rows, I would suggest loading the whole file into memory instead of reading it every time, though.

Comment: The `reader` should really be created within a surrounding `with-open` form.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to clojure, could you give more info of the loading in memory? Maybe some docs?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a functional parser library such as dj-peg (which I wrote).

https://github.com/bmillare/dj-peg

Then you can write this:

```
 (require '[dj-peg :as p])
 (let [line "@@1 the remaining line\n"
       initial (p/token #"@@\d+\s+)]
       (second (p/parse initial line)))
```

The function parse uses the parser returned by p/token to parse the text in line. It will return a vector with the first value as the result of the parse, and the second is the remaining input. Therefore, if we call second, we get the rest of the line. Running this returns

```
 "the remaining line\n"
```

I recommend checking out the library. It is written in pseudo literate programming style so the source code reads quite smoothly. You should be able to understand the parsing model after going through the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The previously given answer using `line-seq` and destructuring of a regex groups works well for the given use-case.

In a general situation where all you want is string manipulation clojure.core includes the`subs` function. http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/subs

`subs` is implemented using java interop and the substring method of the java String class.

```
user=> (subs "abcdef" 1)
"bcdef"
user=> (subs "abcdef" 2 4)
"cd"
```